# How to decrypt a shifted message with XOR?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, shift, modulo

I have a message `m` that I encrypt by the code

```
c = m xor [m<<6] xor [m<<10]
```

(`m<<x` means that I shift it by x bits - eg 1001<<2 = 0100)

I need to decrypt this message.

I have tried code like:

```
c xor [c<<6] xor [c<<10]
```

OR

```
c xor [c>>6] xor [c>>10]
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: Just write down what is in each bit position and you should be able to figure this out on your own. For example, bits 0-5 of `c` are exactly bits 0-5 of `m`. Now bit 6 of `c` is equal to bit 6 of `m` xored with bit 0 of `m`, but you already have bit 0 of `m` so you can recover bit 6 of `m`. And so on.

Comment: Or you could just wait for someone to do all your work for you, it can happen on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The function `c = m xor [m<<6] xor [m<<10]` is a bijection (i.e. reversible on a given modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup>). So you're good to go...

Just piece-wise de-XOR the value by 6 and 10 bits, starting from the lowest bits.

```
int main() {
    uint32_t n = 0xfffffff;
    for (uint32_t m = 0; m < n; ++m) {

        uint32_t c = m ^ (m << 6) ^ (m << 10); // c = encrypted value

        uint32_t x = c;
        x ^= ((x &       0x3F) << 6);
        x ^= ((x &      0x3FF) << 10);
        x ^= ((x &      0xFC0) << 6);
        x ^= ((x &    0x3F000) << 6);
        x ^= ((x &    0xFFC00) << 10);
        x ^= ((x &   0xFC0000) << 6);
        x ^= ((x & 0x3F000000) << 6);
        x ^= ((x & 0x3FF00000) << 10);

        if (m != x) {
            printf("Mismatch: %X > %X > %X\n", m, c, x); // should never happen
            break;
        }
    }
}
```